# How many of The Twenties are enumerated?

Tags: harry-harrison

In the book *Planet of the Damned* by Harry Harrison (which I admit I haven't read in over 30 years, but I was talking about it with my son), there's a planetwide Olympics style game called The Twenties that is literally twenty events everyone competes in and the winner gets the best overall score.  I remember it was very multidisciplinary, including both raw physical challenges like running, skill challenges like fencing and mental challenges like poetry. Does the book or any subsequent authors notes/interviews enumerate all twenty? If not, which ones are explicitly mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book specifically mentions ski-jumping, archery, fencing, chess, poetry, and rifle shooting—prone.

The author uses the phrase 'a double-decathlon' more than once, and clearly many events are related to combat (the mention of 'rifle-shooting—prone' implies more than one rifle event).
The hero is skilled with hand guns, unarmed combat, and uses karate moves.

The games originated in the distant past as a plan (organized by sociologists) to help the planet to escape from a mire of alcoholism and violence. One character says, "Personal honor was emphasized in order to encourage dueling, and this lead to a heightened interest in the techniques of personal combat ... organized competitions could be more interesting than haphazard encounters."

However the games are a very small part of the book: the hero wins his last contest in the first chapter, and is immediately—and unexpectedly—recruited for an interstellar mission that dwarfs his previous life.

Although I wouldn't call this Harrison's best work, the story offers interesting comments about a society's adaptations, and how once-positive adaptations can become harmful as the world changes.

Comment: The sequel, Planet of no return, also adds weight lifting explicitly, and sprinting as likely.